# Converting a Collection in a generic way in Java

Tags: java, object, generics, converters

I am trying to convert a Collection of objects that implement DomainEntity to a Collection of objects that implement DomainEntityDTO. DomainEntity objects provide a method toDTO() to do the conversion.

Here is my code.

```
public class EntityCollectionConverter<T  extends DomainEntityDTO, Y extends DomainEntity> {

    public Collection<T> convert(Collection<Y> collection){

        Collection<T> dtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DomainEntity domainObject : collection) {
            DomainEntityDTO dto = domainObject.toDTO();
            dtoList.add(dto); // Compiler: "T cannot be applied to DomainEntityDTO"
        }
        return dtoList;

    }
}
```

The line `dtoList.add(dto);` doesn't compile, because "T cannot be applied to DomainEntityDTO'.

The interface DomainEntity looks like this:

```
public interface DomainEntity {
    Long getId();

    <T extends DomainEntityDTO> T toDTO();
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: `<T extends DomainEntityDTO> T toDTO()` doesn't make any sense.  It cannot know what `T` is.

Comment: It'd make more sense to have `interface DomainEntity<T extends DomainEntityDTO> { Long getId(); T toDTO(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your variable of type `T`.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I changed `DomainEntityDTO dto = domainObject.toDTO()` to `T dto = domainObject.toDTO()` and that works. I assumed the List would accept a DomainEntityDTO because it should be aware that T extends DomainEntityDTO....

Comment: @Julius: `T` is some type that extends `DomainEntityDTO`.  Not all `DomainEntityDTO`s are `T`s.